# Vagrant VMs can talk to each other, but I can't reach HTTP from the host

Tags: solr, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have 5 VMs on 192.168.56.*:

- .19 - Zookeeper
- .20 - Solr1
- .21 - Solr2
- .22 - Solr3
- .23 - Solr4

This is my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  # config.vm.box = "base"

  (1..4).each do |x|
    ip = 20
    config.vm.define "solr#{x}" do |solr|
      solr.vm.box = 'ubuntu/wily64'
      solr.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.#{ip}", bridge: "Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205"
      ip = ip + 1
      solr.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = 2048
        #v.cpus = 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have Apache HTTP on port 80 and Solr on port 8983. I can do `wget 192.168.56.20:8983` from the ZooKeeper VM and it downloads the main page. When I try to hit 192.168.56.20:8983 from the host OS, it just hangs. Firewall rules are in place that open up those ports, so no idea why .19 can access Solr, but the host cannot.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you just ping `192.168.56.20` from the host to check if its global network issue or ZooKeeper port issue ?